# John the Ripper / Hashcat rule, reject candidate if char at position X is the same as character at position Y

Tags: hash, hashcat, john-the-ripper, wordlist

I'm using John to generate some word lists and I'm trying to figure out the most optimized way to do the next step. What I want to do is add ever possible 3 digit number to a set where the first digit of the number is not the same as the first digit in the set

Set example `123ABC`

to add

`+ 213 = 123ABC213` **OK**

`+ 131 = 123ABC131` **REJECT**

I see rules that reject unless a string includes, but not a comparison function like this.

I could make the whole list and prune it after with a python script, but it would be way bigger than needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you speak more to why you're building wordlists externally, and/or what the target framework is that will be consuming the wordlist? If you're using hashcat, and using a reasonably fast hash, generating them on-GPU is likely to be more efficient (faster, less disk space, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make Hashcat output the list to stdout and pipe the output to a python script that filters it, then pipe the output to another instance of Hashcat (or John).

```
hashcat --stdout [list generation options] | python_filter | hashcat -a 0 -m HASH_TYPE HASH_FILE
```

I am not aware of rules in hashcat that would do this comparison, I hope this helps.